# How to save specific WhatsApp video when by default Media Visibility is off?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, file-management, media-files

I normally have the Media Visibility setting off so it doesn't store WhatsApp media on my phone but recently a friend sent some videos I want to transfer to computer/email. I cannot find these anywhere - I looked in the File Manager for all possible WhatsApp folders, both internal and SD card. I changed the Media Visibility to "on" but it's not a "new" video so it still doesn't save them. It's gotta be downloaded somewhere on my phone - is there any way to transfer them? The "Share" function only allows forwarding to other WhatsApp contacts and not email etc

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally found a way. From the chat, I have to click the group of videos, then tap and hold on one specific video, then the "Share" button shows up to share through email. Gotta do the videos one at a time - it won't show the Share button for multiple videos selected, only the Forward button.